# Webservices deployment issue in mvc asp .net

Tags: sql, web-services, model-view-controller, iis, gac

I am getting exception while deploying traditional web service on server. While sending a soap request it generates the following exception-

"Server was unable to process request. ---> Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information."

And after lot of Googling , I got to know that this is the issue of missing assemblies. Not sure which assembly is missing.

Any one have knowledge on this please comment.

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you are missing an assembly in your Visual Studio solution / project. It should be a simple matter of referencing the missing (or GAC) component and include it as part of the solution build.

Comment: Is there any way to find missing assemblies in the solution as I am not able to track it.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing the following :-

1. Open the reference tab and one-by-one for each assembly in its properties window, set its `Copy Local` property to `True`
2. Rebuild the project, this will copy all the required assemblies into the bin folder
3. Copy these assemblies to the bin folder on server.

I hope it might get things fixed for you

Comment: Thanks, I am trying this solution let you know when my problem will resolved.

Comment: Is MVC installed on your server ?? What error message are you getting right now ??

Comment: No, MVC is not installed as the minimum requirement is the Sql server. I have deployed MVC application earlier on the server and it is running fine but now , I am deploying a webservice there and it's giving error.

Comment: If MVC is not installed then you also need to deploy the Asp.net MVC dependable assemblies. You can visit [Bin deploy](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/05/25/bin-deploying-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx) to see the required assemblies